# Xcode showing incorrect git status

Tags: xcode, git

I have an Xcode project with one related Xcode project. My dependency has some source files with the correct git status.

The dependency however, has multiple dependencies of it's all. Xcode is showing "A" for every file in the grandchild level of dependencies.

```
XcodeProject
  Related XcodeProject
    Grandchild "Dependencies" directory, all have "A"
```

How do I get Xcode to show the correct status?

Comment: Basically I would recommend: don't even try. Xcode's built-in git tools are terrible. Use the command line or something like Sourcetree that knows what it's doing.

Comment: Ha. It was fixed at some point. Maybe there was a local config or something that I applied to resolve this before.